# Nginx URL forwarder to another domain

Tags: nginx

How can I redirect someone from one domain to another whilst keeping the current URL path?

**For example:**

- `example.com/ABC` -> `example2.com/file.html?x=ABC`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a rewrite rule to forward from the old domain to the new one.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 http://new.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

**Documentation:** http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/converting_rewrite_rules.html